# How to deal with paypal claims?

Tags: business, fraud

So, I shipped an item to a buyer.
When the product was delivered, the buyer told me by email the color of the product is different from the colors showed in the photo on my store. He attached me the photo of the product he get, but there isn't much difference. The product in the photo is in light red, while the product on his photo is in dark red.

That aside, in my ToS, I cleary specify that the colors of the photo in the store are only illustrative and the colors of the product the clients are going to get may differ a little bit. He accepted this term when he purchased the product, by ticking a checkbox.

Just because I hate chargebacks, I told him I was willing to give him half price refund and he can keep the product. He refused, and he started a claim on Paypal.

Now on the claim he is saying to paypal just lies. He doesn't talk anymore about different colors, he say the product was broken and dirty when was delivered, the package he accepted was already open, and that he was asking me for a refund all of the time but I never answered to his questions, even if I was the first one to suggest him an half price refund and keeping the product and I always answered as soon as possible, we sent each others about 10 emails.

I don't know what to do anymore. I'm making very few sells online, usually just a couple of sells every month, and all my earning are nulled by this kind of people that I'm facing very often. And it doesn't matter what I say to Paypal, what proof of ToS acceptance I sent them, they always side with the buyer. For example in this case, how can I prove to Paypal what he is saying are just lies? I would NEVER send a dirty or not working product, but what can I do to prove it? Nothing.

So, I would like to know how to deal with Paypal in such cases. How to proves he is saying lies?

Comment: The customer paid for a product. They did not read the terms and conditions of doing business with you, but accepted them anyway. They are unhappy their product was the exact colour they purchased. They are now lying to PayPal in order to get a product for free. This is fraud and the buyer is now open to civil suit and criminal prosecution. If PayPal have contacted you about this, inform them of what has really happened and include the email chain sent between you and the customer. If PayPal go ahead and issue the refund anyway, either lawyer up or write it off

Answer (score 1):

### Don’t contest chargebacks

First, most parts of the world provide strong consumer protection law. If the product *is* a different colour for example, *you* will be breaching the law if you do not replace or refund the item, even if the difference is slight.

Second, your agreement with PayPall means you can’t win. Their business model relies on consumer trust that they will fight for the consumer, they won’t fight for the vendor.

Third, an unhappy customer is an opportunity to either get great publicity for your business or terrible publicity based on how you handle it. Bad reviews go around the world in an instant and last forever.

Fourth, chargebacks are a cost of doing business - set your prices accordingly.